# What happens when RRT is used for a configuration space with no solution?

Tags: graph-algorithm, path-finding, robotics, motion-planning

What happens when RRT or its variants (e.g. RRT-connect) is used for a configuration space with no solution? (for example, when none of the existing paths is free of collision)

Does it just loop forever?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it loops forever until it meets some sort of termination condition (e.g. exceeds a set planning time limit).